# Use zend_lucene_search with Zend_Paginator cache

Tags: zend-framework, zend-search-lucene, zend-paginator

I want to cache my results from Zend_Lucene_Search using Zend_Paginator::setCache()

I get the following error:

```
Warning: fseek() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given
```

Here is the portion of code:

```
// Load index
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open(APPLICATION_PATH . '/indexes');
// Paginate
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($index->find($query));
$paginator->setCache($this->_cache);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage($items);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
// Send to view
$this->view->hits = $paginator;
```

In other areas of the site where I use the same technique to cache paginated results that are not from Zend_Lucene_Search, this works fine.

I read somewhere that storing results in a session or cache destroys the lucene document and that you have to convert the QueryHit objects to stdClass objects, but how? Does this work?

Answer (score 3):

Ok solved it, I was overthinking it

```
$hits = $index->find($query);
$this->view->totalHits = count($hits);
// Convert to stdClass to allow caching
foreach ($hits as $i => $hit) {
    $resultsArray[$i] = new stdClass();
    $doc = $hit->getDocument();
    foreach($doc->getFieldNames() as $field){
        $resultsArray[$i]->{$field} = $hit->{$field};
    }
}
// Paginate
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($resultsArray);
$paginator->setCache($this->_cache);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage($items);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
// Send to view
$this->view->hits = $paginator;
```